# Button redirection using Ruby on Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, button

I'm just starting out with ruby on rails and web applications. I just finished implementing a database with ruby. I'm having trouble making my buttons in the homepage redirect to the views I'd like them to go to. I'm sure it's something very simple but I haven't been able to find a way to do it.

Here is a link to the idea. http://mauricegs.imgur.com/buttons

You press the button that says "Productos" and it should send you to the "Productos" view. I'm not sure what I should add at reference for productos
Thanks

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have an `index` action on your `ProductosController` and a route to the view:

`<%= button_to "Productos", productos_path, method: :get %>`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of
`<a href='#productos'>PRODUCTOS</a>`

Write rails link

`<%= link_to 'PRODUCTOS', productos_path, class: 'button alt' %>`

Comment: can you display your routes.rb and welcome_controller.rb

Answer (score 0):

For a route declared like this...

`get '/productos', to: 'productos#index', as: 'productos'`

...Rails gives you a helper method `productos_path` which evaluates to the the URL of that route. You can then use than in a button as RobM showed.

If productos is a resource (meaning you have `resources :productos` in your routes file), the above route will have been automatically added and you'll still have the `productos_path` helper.